# Download image from a web (direct link) with PHP

Tags: php

Hey, I've got a bunch of URLs in a .txt file, lets say:

> www.example.com/image1.png
>   www.example.com/image2.png
>   www.example.com/image3.png
>   www.example.com/image4.png
>   www.example.com/image5.png
>   ...
>   www.example.com/image900.png

I want, with PHP, to read that list and save those images to a folder.
Reading that list line by line is easy, but I've got no idea how to save them to disk.

Thanks!

Comment: @user691220: PHP class to use GD or cURL to download a remote image -- http://www.bitrepository.com/download-image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it might be possible like this:

```
file_put_contents('/dest/file.png',file_get_contents('http://src.com/image.png'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use combination of [file_get_contents()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Perl rather than php as PHP needs a webserver and perl can do it directly

but you can use Curl as follows

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/image.php');
$fp = fopen('/my/folder/flower.gif', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: php does not need web-server - although a web-server environment is probably the most common way of running it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to fetch images then [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to 'save' them.